# jquery .load issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

i am trying to display an element of a certain view inside another view in asp-mvc4

in index1.cshtml:

```
<div id="divToUpdate"></div>
```

in index2.cshtml:

```
<div id="sss"><table id="grid1"></table></div>
<div id="fff">Hello!</div>
```

in my javascript file:

```
 $('#ThisIsALink').click(function () {
    $('#divToUpdate').load('../Employee/Index #fff');
});
```

this script will show "Hello!" in the div in index1.cshtml... but if i write '../Employee/Index #sss' instead, my table (which is actually a jqgrid) is not shown. why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that your table is created by javascript.

> When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector
>   expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being
>   removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If
>   .load() is called with a selector expression appended to the URL,
>   however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated,
>   and thus are not executed.

The javascript used for your table `jqgrid` will not be executed, so your jqgrid will not be shown.

Comment: ok the solution here is to put the jqgrid in the function of click :)